# Link within flash file posted on facebook wall possible?

Tags: python, flash, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there anyway I can add a link to a flash file I post on my wall using the rest/graph api, such that when a user clicks on the flash file playing, it takes them to my app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose so... just set a click event handler *inside* the Flash movie to redirect the user to wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That doesn't seem to work, for some reason when I click on a button with an action link, it goes to the site I mentioned on my local machine, but not when it's posted on a wall. Do you know of any other way? Thanks again

Comment: Hmm, no. But you can try redirecting the top window. top.location(), something like that. That works for me on a html app, i never tried it on Flash though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still require this , But here is the solution to what you are seeking: 
Use the Feed dialog , and specify in the link parameter the URL of your APP , and in the source parameter , the URL of the flash file you want to post.